# Using String.replace for copys of final Strings

Tags: java, string, replace, immutability, final

I have the following Test:

```
public void testStringReplace()
    {    
        final String placeholder = "$ph$";
        final String template = "<test>" + placeholder + "</test>";
        final String result = "<test>Hello!</test>";

        String copyOfTemplate = template;
        copyOfTemplate.replace(placeholder, "Hello!");

        if(!copyOfTemplate.equals(result));
            fail();
    }
```

The test always fails, but why? How do I have to define `copyOfTemplate`, to be able to change it? Or am I missing some other detail here?

Comment: copyOfTemplate = copyOfTemplate.replace(placeholder, "Hello!");

Comment: `if(!copyOfTemplate.equals(result));` <-- **Remove that semicolon at the end!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String is immutable so calling

```
copyOfTemplate.replace(placeholder, "Hello!");
```

without assigning it to anything effectively does nothing. It returns a new string with the replacement, which you're ignoring. Any half-decent IDE will warn you about this:

[image: IDE warning]

Also, `String copyOfTemplate = template` doesn't really do anything either. It's not a copy. It's just a new variable pointing to the same underlying string. There is no method to copy a string because, again, strings are immutable so a copy becomes useless.

You want

```
String copyOfTemplate = template.replace(placeholder, "Hello!");
```

I suggest reading the [Oracle tutorial on strings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html). It seems like you've missed some of the fundamentals.

Answer (score 0):

As strings are immutable, `opyOfTemplate.replace(placeholder, "Hello!");` produces a new string. So, you have to review your variable

`copyOfTemplate = copyOfTemplate.replace(placeholder, "Hello!");`

Answer (score 0):

I see two main problems in your code:

- Your use of [String#replace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence))

  `copyOfTemplate.replace(placeholder, "Hello!");` returns a new string, it doesn't upadate it. You have to assign it to a new variable.
- The `if` statement at the end

  `if(!copyOfTemplate.equals(result));` Since you added a semicolon, the if does nothing, and you always reach the `fail()` method. it's as if you wrote:

  ```
  if(!copyOfTemplate.equals(result)) {

  }
  fail();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Commented some of the mistakes in your code below -

```
 final String placeholder = "$ph$";
final String template = "<test>" + placeholder + "</test>";
final String result = "<test>Hello!</test>";

String copyOfTemplate = template;
copyOfTemplate = copyOfTemplate.replace(placeholder, "Hello!"); 
// you cannot change existing object because string is immutable

if(!copyOfTemplate.equals(result)) // semi colon removed
    fail();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        final StringBuilder placeholder = new StringBuilder("$ph$");
        final StringBuilder template = new StringBuilder("<test>" + placeholder + "</test>");
        final StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("<test>Hello!</test>");

        replaceString(template, placeholder.toString(), "Hello!");
        System.out.println(template);

    }

    public static void replaceString(StringBuilder sb, String toReplace, String replacement) {
        int index = -1;
        while ((index = sb.lastIndexOf(toReplace)) != -1) {
            sb.replace(index, index + toReplace.length(), replacement);
        }
    }
```